# Problema com o componente rich:suggestionbox no IE

Tags: jsf-2.2, internet-explorer-8, rich-faces

Deparamo-nos com um problema no componente rich:suggestionbox no browser IE 8.

Quando a lista do suggestion aparece e o usuário clica dentro do suggestion, mas em nenhum item da lista, o suggestion é "fechado" (desaparece), no entanto continua presente. Consegui ver isso usando o depurador do IE.

A duas figuras abaixo ilustram o cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois disso, nessa area delimitada pela linha azul não recebe mais clique do mouse.
Alguém ja se deparou com essa situação e já conseguiu resolvê-la?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.